# MSAL in Sngular SPA app signs out the user in absolute 24 hours when session is set on rolling

Tags: azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c

I have 2 Angular apps running in two different subdomains, I have implemented SSO for both my apps I would like to configure the user session in Azure AD B2C so that:

- A user who has not been active for more than 1 day will be logged out and forced to sign in again.
- If they continuously use the app then they their session will be able to keep on using the app more many days

I have been banging my head upon this to set this thing up for my app. It is no where given that how to setup the session configuration for a typical SPA to maintain the user session.

The issue is user is logged out after absolute 24 hours of login even if he is using the app.

Azure settings are attached.

[Azure Settings Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n7Wq.png)

[Azure Settings Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKGTQ.png)